# How can I pass an ArrayList from one servlet another?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I have already sent arraylist1 from one servlet to another. It works. Now I want to pass arraylist2 to another jsp/servlet, but I get an error: `java.util.nullPointer Exception`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: We can't magically solve your problem unless you post some code and explain where you're facing a problem.

Comment: data1.add(noofrows);
            RequestDispatcher disp1;
            disp1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("data1", data1);

Comment: the above code is send the value of noofrows from conn.java to index.jsp... it works..

Comment: RequestDispatcher disp2;
                disp2 = request.getRequestDispatcher("NewServlet.java");
                request.setAttribute("data2", data2);

Comment: the second code is data2 . i want to send this data2 to NewServlet.java but it gives only error... null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

```
RequestDispatcher disp2 = request.getRequestDispatcher("NewServlet.java");
```

should be

```
RequestDispatcher disp2 = request.getRequestDispatcher(pathToYourServlet);
```

The path is the end of the page adress:
http://localhost/yourApp/**pathToYourServlet**

Comment: same packge... how do i specific? shall i specific that packge name?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the package or the class name, the path defines the URL used to access the Servlet, it is defined in the web.xml or with @Path annotations if you're using J2EE 6

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the full stack trace of the null pointer to establish where it is coming from. Then you should debug through that line by line to see where the null is. From there you should be able to back trace to the source. These are very general statements, but they are how I would approach your problem given the little information provided.

Comment: i hav added and retrivd in that same servlet.it givs the values. but if i pass to another servlt givs an exception nly... what can i do?