# how can i pass more than one array list from single servlet to two more jsp or servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

i want to pass one arraylist for one jsp and another one arraylist for another one servlet from same servlet . i have already sent that first arraylist to servlet to jsp it works.but i want to sent another one arraylist to another servlet, am using same code syntax but it doesn't works? what can i do?

Comment: you are not giving enough information

Comment: am using 2 ArrayLists(data1,data2) in Same servlet(conn.java).

Comment: i have stored one value in data1 and more than one values in data2, i have sent data1 to one jsp(index.jsp) using requestdispatcher and get a value in index.jsp using request.getAttribute(data1), its works.

Comment: but the problem is, am using the same code for storing and retrieving in data2, sent to another java(NewServlet.java) from same servlet , but it doesn't work. it gives an Exception::: java.util.NullPointer Exception. what can i do?

Comment: Do not doublepost questions. Edit your original question to clarify the matter more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321553/how-can-i-pass-an-arraylist-from-one-servlet-another and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321151/how-to-pass-array-from-one-servlet-to-another-servlet

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean when you say that you pass array list from servlet to jsp?
If you are forwarding or redirecting HTTP request you can pass as many parameters as you wish using HTTP session attributes.

Comment: pls give me the code for that, in the last 3 days, i got only errors on that.. pls

Answer (score 0):

From my guess, I belive what you are looking for is the MVC pattern for passing you model (List) to view (JSP). Here is the best example I found with google of [how to use MVC with JSP](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm)

If you have problem with adopting the code to work with yours, please give me explanation of what the problem is and what codes or error messages look like. It will be more helpful to those who try to help.